# Mongo DB Java 3.x Driver - Group By Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I'd like to learn how to implement `group by` query using `Mongo DB Java 3.x Driver`. I want to group my collection through the `usernames`, and sort the results by the `count` of results `DESC`.

Here is the shell query which I want to implement the `Java` equivalent:

```
db.stream.aggregate({ $group: {_id: '$username', tweetCount: {$sum: 1} } }, { $sort: {tweetCount: -1} } );
```

Here is the `Java` code that I have implemented:

```
BasicDBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "username");

// count the results and store into countOfResults
groupFields.put("countOfResults", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);


// sort the results by countOfResults DESC
BasicDBObject sortFields = new BasicDBObject("countOfResults", -1);
BasicDBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", sortFields);

List < BasicDBObject > pipeline = new ArrayList < BasicDBObject > ();
pipeline.add(group);
pipeline.add(sort);

AggregateIterable < Document > output = collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

The result I need is the count of documents grouped by `username`. `countOfResults` returns the **total number** of the documents the collection has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try not to use old object (`BasicDBObject`) types with Mongo 3.x. You can try something like this.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

Bson group = group("$username", sum("tweetCount", 1));
Bson sort = sort(new Document("tweetCount", -1));
AggregateIterable <Document> output = collection.aggregate(asList(group, sort));
```