# How can i groupby a column in Mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, group-by

```
{"amount":100,"NAME":"dgsdg","ID":1}
{"amount":200,"NAME":"fdfd","ID":2}
{"amount":300,"NAME":"jfhjd","ID":3}
{"amount":400,"NAME":"kjhfjh","ID":4}
{"amount":500,"NAME":"kjjdj","ID":5}
{"amount":300,"NAME":"fdfd","ID":6}
```

I want to perform group By Name
I am able to do till getting the collection.

```
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("db");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
 MongoCollection<Document> myColl =  (MongoCollection<Document>) collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.group("$Name", Accumulators.sum("amount", 1))));
          FindIterable<org.bson.Document> it = myColl.find();

            MongoCursor<org.bson.Document> cursor = it.iterator();
            //System.out.println(cursor.next());
            Map s = cursor.next();
            JSONObject j = new JSONObject(s);
```

giving me the exception: **java.lang.ClassCastException:com.mongodb.AggregateIterableImpl cannot be cast to com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection**

Comment: use the aggregation framework. Take a look at [**$group**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/aggregation/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/veeram i have gone through the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41578061/7720299)  you answered where i got a solution, I have done this                                                                    `Bson group = group("$NAME");
Bson sort = sort(new Document("amount", -1));
AggregateIterable <Document> output = collection.aggregate(asList(group,sort));
MongoCursor<org.bson.Document> cursor = output.iterator();
while(cursor.hasNext()){
System.out.println(cursor.next());` By this i am able to retrieve only name column, I want to print amount too.

Comment: You forgot a crucial step in the group pipeline, you missed the `sum()` accumulator as `Bson group = group("$NAME", sum("amount", "$amount")); Bson sort = sort(new Document("amount", -1)); AggregateIterable <Document> output = collection.aggregate(asList(group, sort)); MongoCursor<org.bson.Document> cursor = output.iterator(); while(cursor.hasNext()){ System.out.println(cursor.next());`

Comment: It worked to some point, But result i am getting: Document{{_id=kjjdj, amount=500}} Document{{_id=kjhfjh, amount=400}} Document{{_id=jfhjd, amount=300}} Document{{_id=fdfd, amount=500}} Document{{_id=dgsdg, amount=100}} doesnot follow order i.e the first document should be {"amount":100,"NAME":"dgsdg","ID":1} but i am getting the documents in reverse order @http://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam

Comment: To answer your follow-up question, you need to sort on both fields i.e. `Bson sort = sort(new Document("_id", 1).append("amount", -1));`

Comment: It worked @chridam