# Retrieve columns using $project in mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

```
db.test.aggregate( {$project : { ID : 1, amount : 1, NAME : 1}})
```

gives me the result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cbbc909b76f65dd4e6244e"), "ID" : 1, "NAME" : "dgsdg", "amount" : 600}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cbbc909b76f65dd4e6244f"), "ID" : 2, "NAME" : "fdfd", "amount" : 200}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cbbc909b76f65dd4e62450"), "ID" : 3, "NAME" : "jfhjd", "amount" : 300}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cbbc909b76f65dd4e62451"), "ID" : 4, "NAME" : "kjhfjh", "amount" : 400}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cbbc909b76f65dd4e62452"), "ID" : 5, "NAME" : "kjjdj", "amount" : 500}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cbbc909b76f65dd4e62453"), "ID" : 6, "NAME" : "fdfd", "amount" : 300}
```

When i do this in java:

```
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("NAME", 1)
         .append("amount", 1).append("ID", 1));
DBObject group1 = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", "$NAME"));
        AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(project,group1);
```

gives me the result :

```
{ "_id" : "kjjdj"}
```

How can i achieve the below result with the above java code:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cbbc909b76f65dd4e6244e"), "ID" : 1, "NAME" : "dgsdg", "amount" : 600}
```

Comment: Why are you grouping in your java code ?

Comment: I want to group by Name and display all columns in the result like:                `{ "_id" : ObjectId("58cbbc909b76f65dd4e6244e"), "ID" : 1, "NAME" : "dgsdg", "amount" : 600}` - Veeram

Comment: without grouping i got the expected result, But how can i perform group by here? - Veeram

Comment: Why do you need grouping if your expected output is same as after project ? Please update your post with explanation

Comment: I want to group by name and get sum of amount too, please find the edited code @Veeram

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo DB Java 3.x Driver - Group By Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577906/mongo-db-java-3-x-driver-group-by-query)

Comment: the above doesnot give me all the columns @Veeram

Comment: Please add first accumulator to all the the fields you need from the grouping stage. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/. Something like `Bson group = group("$NAME", sum("amount", 1), first("ID", "$ID"))` You can remove the project stage.

Comment: I am getting the result as:                                                                                 `Document{{_id=kjjdj, amount=1, ID=5}}
Document{{_id=kjhfjh, amount=1, ID=4}}
Document{{_id=jfhjd, amount=1, ID=3}}
Document{{_id=fdfd, amount=2, ID=2}}
Document{{_id=dgsdg, amount=1, ID=1}}`
why is the amount not showing correctly @Veeram

Comment: Can I see your query ?

Comment: `Bson group = group("$NAME", sum("amount", 1), first("ID", "$ID"));

AggregateIterable <Document> output = contCol1.aggregate(asList(group));
Iterator<Document> cursor =  output.iterator();
while(cursor.hasNext()){
 System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
  }`              @Veeram

Comment: Sorry try `Bson group = group("$NAME", sum("amount", "$amount"), first("ID", "$ID"));  AggregateIterable <Document> output = contCol1.aggregate(asList(group)); Iterator<Document> cursor =  output.iterator(); while(cursor.hasNext()){  System.out.println(cursor.next()); }   }`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Veeram