# How can i get the count of documents of a collection with a where condition in mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, count

```
Document{{_id=trrrrr, ID=7, NAME=trrrrr, amount=700.0}}
Document{{_id=kjjdj, ID=6, NAME=kjjdj, amount=100.0}}
Document{{_id=dgsdg, ID=5, NAME=dgsdg, amount=500.0}}
Document{{_id=fdfd, ID=2, NAME=fdfd, amount=300.0}}
Document{{_id=cggggg, ID=1, NAME=cggggg, amount=600.0}}
Document{{_id=kjhfjh, ID=3, NAME=kjhfjh, amount=300.0}}
```

these are the documents of a collection, I want to perform count operation where NAME =fdfd i.e (select count(*) from table group by NAME=fdfd)

How can i achieve this in java?

Comment: Please read java docs http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#count-org.bson.conversions.Bson-

Comment: i have gone through the link, But i want to perform gorup by along with count(*) @Veeram

Comment: Please don't edit post  after it has been marked duplicate. Here is the link for grouping with count. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41577906/2683814

Comment: you took me wrong, I want to perform select NAME,count(*) from table group by NAME, can you give me a hint regarding this  @Veeram

Comment: Show me what you have tried. I'll try to help you. Please make sure next time you ask question you include all the details as it makes easy to help you quickly.